# Save & return feature

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way for participants to get a reminder to finish their survey if they have not returned after a set time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not have a way to set up any kind of a reminder email, that the system would automate. You can go to your entries page, and filter by Incomplete entries. You could then send out a manual email to nudge or remind users that they have yet to finish filling out the form. This can be best done with the [Entry Sharing](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/79/entries/sharing-entries) feature.